# Is it some sort of gambling when we take out our Social Security in the US?

Tags: united-states, retirement, social-security

I found that it could be like this:

If we take out our Social Security at the age of:

```
62      $2000 / month
70      $4000 / month
```

and I calculated that it is assuming we live to age 78, then the total payout amount are the same.

However, does that mean, let's say if we live to age 95 or 100, then if we start taking money out at age 62, then we only have $2000 / month from age 78 to 100, while if we starting doing it at age 70, then it is $4000 / month from age 78 to 100?  That's quite a bit of life style difference with double the amount of money.

However, God forbids, for somebody who start taking it out at age 70 but lives to age 72 or 73, that means they save up all their life for social security, and they can only take it out for 2 or 3 years?

It seems a bit of gambling... is it so?  (the word "security" has a "safety" meaning, but it doesn't go too well with the "gambling" idea).

Comment: If you wait until age 70 to begin SS, how much will you get in benefits if you die at age 69?

Comment: if you die at age 69, it doesn't do anything, that's why it is a gamble

Comment: Exactly.  The optimal result is based on your longevity which can't be known except in hindsight.

Comment: If you buy life insurance, you're betting that you're going to die. True, but not particularly useful.

Comment: the point is, if we buy life insurance or annuity, it is some sort of gamble, but it is an option. We don't have to buy it.  But something that is universal for everybody, and we have to take it as a gamble? Longevity, we cannot predict, but what time we take out our money, we have to play into the gambling of it?

Answer (score 3):

In a sense, all insurance could be considered "gambling" in the sense that the ROI has an element that you don't have control over. Annuities (such as SS) are just a form of insurance policy that protects you against the risk of losing your income when you get too old or infirmed to work.

In the spirit of the question, I'd say no. What you buy with your contributions is more than just the payout, it is the transfer of that risk to the Government that you might outlive your money/earning potential. That is pretty much guaranteed with Social Security, so it is indeed a sure bet as long as the program remains solvent.

If you take such a narrow interpretation of "gambling" to mean any financial  transaction that involves risk, then pretty much EVERYTHING you do is a gamble. You take a job and you don't get the pay raises you expect. You buy a house that might go down in value.

The important thing here is how it is relevant to any decisions you might make. Are you planning to opt out of social security somehow? If not, what does it matter?

Comment: the program could actually take into consideration actuary principles, and say, only 15% of the people live past age 90, and only 5% of people live past 100, then the program can take care of them by increasing the amount they receive.  So instead of letting a person who is age 95 to "look for a job" or struggle, the program can cover them.  Then they just have to care about living well, not "if I live well, I will have not enough money and what can I do?"

Comment: @StefanieGauss could, but it's not what it was designed for in the US. In general, the way SS works in the US it's a combination of an accumulated defined benefit pension and a traditional social security insurance as it is known in Europe, and kindof takes the worst from each.

Comment: @StefanieGauss  - I'm not understanding why you are asking this question. Is the point to complain about how Social Security Works, or do you have an actual question?

Answer (score 2):

> If we take out our Social Security at the age of:
>
> 62      $2000 / month
> 70      $4000 / month

If that is from the Social security website there is am important caveat with those numbers:

> At your current earnings rate, if you continue working until...
>
> your full retirement age (67 years), your payment would be about... $medium a month
> age 70, your payment would be about...$large a month
> age 62, your payment would be about... $small a month

Note to get that much at age 70 you need to keep working. So if you stop working earlier in that 62 to 70 range the numbers  at the upper age will not be as high.

This is because the benefit you receive is based on your earning history, if your history isn't as long then it will rely on more early years. That means that if you stop working at 62, or 65 the calculus may change and it will be better to take the money early, because waiting might not result in the expected monthly payments.

Also remember that the Social security payment isn't expected to be the entire amount of retirement income somebody has, they are also expected to have a pension, IRA, and 401(k) accounts. Though each year the percent of people with pensions goes down.